# NOT able to import Folium after showing folium in conda list

Tags: python-3.x, pip, anaconda, conda, folium

I have installed folium using both pip and conda , it got successfully installed infact conda list in particular environment also showing still i can not be able to import the folium.

#Instructions i followed to installed folium are below:-

```
(ML) C:\Users\24HOURS>pip3 install folium
Requirement already satisfied: folium in c:\users\24hours\miniconda3\envs\ml\lib
\site-packages (0.10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\24hours\miniconda3\envs\ml\lib\
site-packages (from folium) (1.19.2)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\24hours\miniconda3\envs\ml\l
ib\site-packages (from folium) (2.25.1)
Requirement already satisfied: branca>=0.3.0 in c:\users\24hours\miniconda3\envs
\ml\lib\site-packages (from folium) (0.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2>=2.9 in c:\users\24hours\miniconda3\envs\m
l\lib\site-packages (from folium) (2.11.3)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in c:\users\24hours\miniconda3\e
nvs\ml\lib\site-packages (from jinja2>=2.9->folium) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<5,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\24hours\miniconda3\
envs\ml\lib\site-packages (from requests->folium) (4.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in c:\users\24hours\miniconda3\envs\
ml\lib\site-packages (from requests->folium) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\24hours\minicon
da3\envs\ml\lib\site-packages (from requests->folium) (1.26.4)
```

Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\24hours\miniconda3
\envs\ml\lib\site-packages (from requests->folium) (2020.12.5)

conda way installation below:-

```
(ML) C:\Users\24HOURS>conda install -c conda-forge folium
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.9.2
  latest version: 4.10.0

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda



## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\24HOURS\miniconda3\envs\ML

  added / updated specs:
    - folium


The following packages will be UPDATED:

  ca-certificates    conda-forge/label/cf202003::ca-certif~ --> conda-forge::ca-
certificates-2020.12.5-h5b45459_0
  folium             conda-forge/label/cf202003::folium-0.~ --> conda-forge::fol
ium-0.12.0-pyhd8ed1ab_1


Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done

(ML) C:\Users\24HOURS>
```

Still I am getting import Error for folium

```
In jupyter notebook

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-1-173c1173bf1c> in <module>
    ----> 1 import folium
    
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folium'
```

Comment: I know I sometimes forget to activate the env. Is it listed correctly in the top right corner of your notebook?

Comment: yes, i have already activated the same environment where i am installing the folium module, infact we can see i am installing inside ML environment name.
After installing i am restarting my kernal also so that module  error wont come but still it is coming. :(

Answer (score 0):

Running following code in terminal fixed it for me

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge folium
```